# variable inside a string used as an os command in python

Tags: python

I need to execute a system command in which there is a variable.In the code below

```
    os.system('SMILExtract -C config/demo/demo1_energy.conf -I user.wav -O csv/user.csv')
```

in the string "**user.wav**", **user** is a variable string and **.wav** is the constant string.How can  include it within the os.system() command

Comment: FYI, it is usually better to use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html) for things like this. It was designed specifically to replace several other, older modules and functions, such as `os.system`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) string?

```
os.system('SMILExtract -C config/demo/demo1_energy.conf -I {0}.wav -O csv/user.csv'.format(somevar))
```

This can be made clean and readable by mapping out the things that can change into various named parameters:

```
cmd_template = 'SMILExtract -C {config_path} -I {wav_base}.wav -O {csv_path}'
os.system(cmd_template.format(
  config_path='config/demo/demo1_energy.conf',
  wav_base='user',
  csv_path='csv/user.csv',
))
```

Comment: how to include if both csv path and output path is a variable ?

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is named `user`, just use string concatenation:

```
os.system('SMILExtract -C config/demo/demo1_energy.conf -I ' + user + '.wav -O csv/user.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use the call function of the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

```
from subprocess import call
varname="test"
user=varname+str(".wav")
options="-C config/demo/demo1_energy.conf -I %s -O csv/user.csv"%(user)

call(["SMILExtract", options])
```

Answer (score 0):

os.system('SMILExtract -C config/demo/demo1_energy.conf -I '+user+'.wav -O csv/user.csv')