# Py (os.path): is there a max. size for a string before an automated breakline / return?

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, feature-extraction, os.path

I hope I am able to describe my problem well, sorry in advance if it's complicated.

**Question:**
Does Python (or the os.path calls) automatically insert a return after an amount of characters?

**Background:**
I try to extract acoustic features from .wav files with the tool openSMILE.
For this purpose I pass the strings of the path (inputfile and outputfile)
via subprocess.

The SMILExtract call takes 3 arguments (-C for config; -I for inputfile -O for output file). I prepare these 3 Arguments with string operations and save the arguments in a list which gets passed to the subprocess call.

```
def extractFeatures(self,inputFile):
    self.openSMILEsettings.append("-I " + inputFile)

    outputFile = os.path.dirname(inputFile) + "/featuresOf_" +os.path.basename(inputFile)[0:-3] + "arff"
    self.openSMILEsettings.append("-O " + outputFile)
    print self.openSMILEsettings[2]
    print ' '.join(self.openSMILEsettings)
    # print subprocess.check_output(['SMILExtract'] + self.openSMILEsettings)

extractFeatures("/media/USERNAME/MountPOINT/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/02003_SomeSesssionNumber1_and2_2323123/audioFile.wav")
```

In the console the output of the print command (print ' '.join(...)) looks alright (example below)

```
-C OSconfig/IS12_speaker_trait.conf -I /media/USERNAME/MountPOINT/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/02003_SomeSesssionNumber1_and2_2323123/audioFile.wav -O /media/USERNAME/MountPOINT/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/02003_SomeSesssionNumber1_and2_2323123/featuresOf_audioFile.arff
```

However when I try to run the code with the subprocess call I get an exception. For debugging purposes I copied the output of the print to a text Editor and it appears that a Return gets entered, it looks like this

```
-C OSconfig/IS12_speaker_trait.conf -I /media/USERNAME/MountPOINT/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/02003_SomeSesssionNumber1_and2_2323123/audioFile.wav -O /media/USERNAME/MountPOINT/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/02003_SomeSesssionNumber1_and2_2323123/featur
esOf_audioFile.arff
```

Comment: What text editor are you using? Is it just built-in word wrap?

Comment: it might be, I use gedit at the moment.

Comment: I imagine that's exactly what's happening. Try to view it with word wrap disabled *or* showing whitespace characters to see if a \n character exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is word wrap, and is caused by your text editor. Essentially, there is no newline character, but your editor cannot show the text on a single line because it's too long. As a result, it's pushing the text to a new line.

You can disable this in gedit by going to View->Preferences->Uncheck "Enable Text Wrapping".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dyno. That explains why there was a return in the texteditor.

I meanwhile found a solution for the exectuion of the SMILExtract call. 
I changed subprocess call to os.system and used a template like explained [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203562/variable-inside-a-string-used-as-an-os-command-in-python?rq=1)

The new call looks like this:

```
def extractFeatures(self,inputFile):
    self.openSMILEsettings.append("-I " + inputFile)
    outputFile = os.path.dirname(inputFile) + "/featuresOf_" +os.path.basename(inputFile)[0:-3] + "arff"
    self.openSMILEsettings.append("-O " + outputFile)
    cmd_template = 'SMILExtract {config_path} {wav_path} {arff_path}'

    os.system(cmd_template.format(
        config_path=self.openSMILEsettings[0],
        wav_path=self.openSMILEsettings[1],
        arff_path=self.openSMILEsettings[2],
        ))
```

This now runs smoothly. Is there any downside to using os.system insted of subprocess?

Comment: I would ask this as a separate question.